# Request for help in solving ODE/PDE coupled equation set

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, matlab, boundary-value-problem

The equation set consists of three equations, two ODEs and a PDE
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
\dfrac {d^{2}u} {dx^{2}}+au-bv=0\\
\dfrac {d^{2}v} {dx^{2}}+av+bu=0\\
c\dfrac {\partial w} {\partial t}=d\dfrac {\partial ^{2}w} {\partial x^{2}}+e\left( u^{2}+v^{2}\right)
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Boundary conditions when $x=0$ :
\begin{equation*}  
\begin{cases}
\dfrac {du} {dx}-fv=g\\
\dfrac {dv} {dx}+fu=g\\ 
\dfrac {\partial w} {\partial x}=hw\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Boundary conditions when $x=1$ :
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
\dfrac {du} {dx}+fv=k\\
\dfrac {dv} {dx}-fu=k\\ 
\dfrac {\partial w} {\partial x}=-hw\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

The initial condition is $w=m$ and $a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, k, m$ are all constant values.

I'm now trying to using MATLAB's ***ode45*** and ***pdetool*** to solve this but boundary conditions in my problem is not fit in pde45 and it is difficult to couple these two functions together.

Best regards.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `bvp4c` or `bvp5c`?: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/boundary-value-problems.html

Comment: @horchler Thank you for your comment. I have read the documentation and found that boundary conditions in this problem can not fit in the requirement of bvp4c and bvp5c.